# Is there a WPF control to select a range looking like a slider?

Tags: wpf, slider

Is there a WPF control looking like a slider (or maybe Slider itself), that has both a minimum and maximum value instead of a single value to let the user select a range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RangeSlider](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/wpf-range-slider-control/) from [AvalonControlsLibrary](http://avaloncontrolslib.codeplex.com/).

Example:

```
<avalon:RangeSlider RangeStart="0" RangeStop="100"
                    RangeSelectionChanged="RangeSlider_RangeSelectionChanged"/>
```

Where avalon is:

```
xmlns:avalon="http://schemas.AvalonControls/AvalonControlsLibrary/Controls"
```

RangeSelectionChanged event hadler:

```
private void RangeSlider_RangeSelectionChanged(object sender, AC.AvalonControlsLibrary.Controls.RangeSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("e.NewRangeStart: " + e.NewRangeStart);
    Console.WriteLine("e.NewRangeStop: " + e.NewRangeStop); 
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/) library provides a great RangeSlider control.  Here is an example of them from the demo application:

[image: Examples of range sliders from the demo application]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. +1

Answer (score 4):

Slider bar has a property IsSelectionRangeEnabled. check the sample:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a9eb8697-3ae4-4045-9508-a75d6168a8af/

Comment: that only allows you to highlight at selection of the slider

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: Avalon controls is the older predecessor to the WPF Extended Toolkit, which now includes the AvalonDock.

RangeSlider is part of the WPF Extended toolkit.

Comment: Extended.Wpf.Toolkit is commercial (free for non-commercial projects)

Answer (score 2):

What i tried is placing two sliders one over he other, so it looks like a range slider
Then, you can set the value, one slider for min and another for max,and add the logic for greater and smaller values. Hope it works, in this case you need not add any external third party library

Answer (score 2):

As *@kmatyaszek* already said [AvalonControlsLibrary](http://avaloncontrolslib.codeplex.com) is great free (*Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)*) Library of controls.

However i found for myself basic styles for **RangeSlider** not very satisfy.

Here is **style for more modern version for it** (RangeSlider.xaml):

```
        <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            xmlns:drawing="clr-namespace:System.Drawing;assembly=System.Drawing" >

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushSliderEdge" Color="LightGray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushSliderActiveArea" Color="DeepSkyBlue" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushSliderThumb" Color="LightSkyBlue" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushSliderThumbBorder" Color="DeepSkyBlue" />

    <Style x:Key="SliderEdge" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
            <Border Height="3" Background="{StaticResource BrushSliderEdge}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushSliderEdge}" BorderThickness="1" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SliderInner" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
            <Border Height="3" Background="{StaticResource BrushSliderActiveArea}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushSliderThumbBorder}" BorderThickness="1" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{StaticResource BrushSliderThumb}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:RangeSlider}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:RangeSlider}">
            <StackPanel Name="PART_RangeSliderContainer" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RepeatButton Name="PART_LeftEdge" Style="{StaticResource SliderEdge}" />
            <Thumb Name="PART_LeftThumb" Cursor="SizeWE" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}" />
            <Thumb Name="PART_MiddleThumb" MinWidth="10" Cursor="ScrollAll" Style="{StaticResource SliderInner}" />
            <Thumb Name="PART_RightThumb" Cursor="SizeWE" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}" />
            <RepeatButton Name="PART_RightEdge" Style="{StaticResource SliderEdge}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is example how it will look *(you can change colors by changing brushes color values)*:

[image]

- Replace with it base style from: 
  http://avaloncontrolslib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/AvalonControlsLibrary/Themes/RangeSlider.xaml
- And use for control: 
  http://avaloncontrolslib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/AvalonControlsLibrary/Controls/RangeSlider.cs

## Example of control usage in .NET 4.5

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Library.WPF;assembly=Library"
         MinWidth="700"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Library;component/WPF/RangeSlider/RangeSlider.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
                <wpf:RangeSlider Width="400"
                                 MinRange="0"
                                 RangeStart="10"
                                 RangeStartSelected="{Binding MyValue_Min}"
                                 RangeStop="100"
                                 RangeStopSelected="{Binding MyValue_Max}" />
 </StackPanel>
```

## In above example:

Assembly where control data located: **Library**

Namespace: **Library.WPF**

- */WPF/RangeSlider/RangeSlider.xaml* <-- xaml style
- */WPF/RangeSlider/RangeSlider.cs* <-- control code

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the RangeSlider by Xceed.

https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/RangeSlider

Comment: Thanks for this add … I liked xceed so it would fit in the project, but I abandoned it some years ago, but good to know in future.